# Normal bundle of a submanifold defined by a submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

If we have a submersion between differential manifolds then the normal bundle of the preimage of a regular value is trivializable? I know it is true if the codomain has dimension one but I do not see how to generalize or if it is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a good exercise for you: If $f\colon X\to Y$ is transverse to $Z$, then $W=f^{-1}(Z)$ is a submanifold whose normal bundle $N(W,X)$ is the pullback of the normal bundle $N(Z,Y)$. Of course, when $Z$ is a point, $N(Z,Y)$ is a trivial bundle.

Comment: Thanks it is a nice excercise. And the normal bundle being trivial implies that the submanifold is orientable?

Comment: @Epet:  Not without assuming something more about $X$ and $Y$.  For example, the projection map $\mathbb{R}P^2\times S^1\rightarrow S^1$ is a submersion with preimages diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: Only if the restriction of $TX$ to $W$ is orientable.

Comment: @Jason but in the same spirit you can do the same with that product projecting to the projective space and the preimage is the circle, and neither X and Y are orientable. So maybe the statement could be with both X and Y orientable, or at least X

Comment: @Epet: The next exercise is this. You have a short exact sequence of vector bundles on $W$: $$0\to TW\to TX|_W \to N(W,X)\to 0.$$ It's pretty straightforward to check that any time you have a short exact sequence of vector bundles, if any two are orientable, then so is the third. (It follows that if one is orientable and another non-orientable, then the remaining one is non-orientable as well.)